# how to determine compatible library version for specific spring boot version

Tags: spring-boot

How can I find out the compatible version of a specific library to pull that matches my spring boot version?

For example, I am fixing a project I inherited that has spring-cloud-openfeign-core 4.0.0 which I suspect is incompatible with spring boot 3.0.2.  The only way I know is to run a project generated by the spring initializr for a custom springboot version but that only works for some libraries